# jQuery select last word after = (equal symbol)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using `$(this).attr("href");` to select the href attribute value of the clicked element, but I need to select only the part after the last '=' symbol.

Example:

href="index.php?con=123&id=123&sel=heyhey"

I only need the last part of the href that is 'heyhey'

How can I select this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without regex -

```
var parts = $(this).attr('href').split('=');
var part = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: Maybe I will need this, so if I need '&sel=heyhey' instead? I mean with the '&' included. How it will looks like?

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "index.php?con=123&id=123&sel=heyhey";
var i = s.lastIndexOf("=");
alert(s.substr(i+1, s.length));
```

EDIT:

doesn't even need of jQuery